# How to display an array representing a folder structure in Laravel Blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Let's say I have a PHP array of arrays representing a folder structure that goes like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "size" => "9.8 MiB"
    "name" => "Game.exe"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "size" => "3.9 MiB"
    "name" => "Launcher.exe"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "size" => "2 MiB"
    "name" => "USRDIR/mask.mpk"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "size" => "1 MiB"
    "name" => "USRDIR/subs.hrt"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "size" => "10 MiB"
    "name" => "USRDIR/fullhd/footage.mkv"
  ]
```

And I want to display this information as a folder structure in HTML using an unordeded list of unordered lists, as such:

```
    <ul class="root-folder">
        <ul class="folder"><span>FOLDERNAME</span>
            <ul class="folder"><span>FOLDERNAME</span>
                <li class="file">FILENAME</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="file">FILENAME</li>
            <li class="file">FILENAME</li>
        <ul>
        <li class="file">FILENAME</li>
        <li class="file">FILENAME</li>
    </ul>
```

The first 2 arrays have a 'name' value formed by a string with the following format: "filename.fileextension", meaning these are files in the root this folder. For these I can just throw a `<li>` element displaying its values inside the master `<ul>`. However, the third array has a 'name' value of "folder/filesize.fileextension", meaning that to represent this visually, I have to make a new `<ul>` with new files inside as `<li>` elements. There's also the fact that the array will name the same folders multiple times if said folders have more than 1 file in them. Then the last array has 2 folders before the file. What would my syntax look like, and am I doing this in a controller and passing an array to the view to display, or in the Blade template by just passing it the original array?

For now this is what I have but I'm kinda lost:

Controller:

```
    $fileArray = [];
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        array_push($fileArray, $file);
        $fileArray[$key]['size'] = formatBits($file['size']);
        $fileArray[$key]['name'] = explode('/', $file['name']);
    }

    return view('single', [
        'fileArray' => $fileArray
    ]);
```

Blade template:

```
    <ul>
        @foreach ($fileArray as $file)
            @if (count($file['name']) > 1)
                @foreach ($file['name'] as $folder)
                    @if ($folder == end($file['name']))
                    <li>
                        <span class="file-icon"></span>{{ $folder }}<span class="file-size">({{ $file['size'] }})
                    </li>
                    @else 
                    <li>
                        <span class="file-icon"></span>{{ $folder }}
                    </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @else
            <li>
                <span class="file-icon"></span>{{ $file['name'][0] }}<span class="file-size">({{ $file['size'] }})
            </li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

This creates a `<li>` element for every instance of a string that got separated from the original pathname string in the controller. You should be able to see how this is problematic, as it creates a new `<li>` for every time a folder name is mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a short idea:

```
$files = Paths::all()->toArray();//lets say you do this to have the array you told us ready

$fileArray = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if(str_contains($file['name'], '/')){
        $split = explode('/', $file['name']);
        $name = last($split);
        $path = array_chunk($split, sizeof($split)-1)[0];
    }else{
        $name = $file['name'];
        $path = [];
    }
    $temp = [['name'=>$name, 'size' => formatBits($file['size'])]]; //single value in array too to ease future headaches
    while( count($path) > 0 ){
        $temp2 = [];
        $temp2[ '/'.last( $path ) ] = $temp;
        array_pop( $path );
        $temp3 = $temp2;
        $temp2 = $temp;
        $temp = $temp3;
    }
    $fileArray = array_merge_recursive($fileArray,$temp);
}

return view('single', compact('fileArray'));
```

In your blade you need to check if the key is in folder syntax.

```
@php
function compareFiles(array $a, array $b){
    if(isset($a['name']) && isset($a['name'])){
        return strcmp($a['name'],$b['name']);
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

function fileSys($fileArray) {
    ksort($fileArray, SORT_STRING); //sorting 'folders' (by key)
    uasort($fileArray, "compareFiles"); //sorting 'files' (by value)
    foreach($fileArray as $key => $value){
        if(str_contains(strval($key), '/')) {
            echo "<li><span class=\"file-icon\"></span>".substr($key, 1)."<ul>";
            filesys($fileArray[$key]);
            echo "</ul></li>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<li><span class=\"file-icon\"></span>".$value['name']."<span class=\"file-size\">(".$value['size'].")</li>";
        }
    }
}
@endphp
<ul>
    {{ fileSys($fileArray) }}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer contains errors... nevertheless, you are on the right track. Here is the corrected version for you to try: [Laravel Playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/19e5967d-ee12-47ea-bcce-960af9480dfa)

Comment: This works with @rozsazoltan's corrections. I can probably figure out the rest, but just in case, any quick way to sort all of the dimensions of the `$fileArray` by sub-array depth, so the folders will be first, and then alphabetically, so folders will be first ordered alphabetically, and then files ordered alphabetically?

Comment: @SimónChasnovsky Done. Check the 2 latest entry in edit history for the whole knowledge.